# How to use the new Visual Studio 2017 cmake features with gitlab CI runners

Tags: cmake, visual-studio-2017, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a gitlab-ci-runner setup for linux in a straight forward way (cmake, make, make test). Here is how it roughly looks:

```yaml
variables:
  GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive

stages:
  - build
  - test

build:
  stage: build
  script: 
    - cd build
    - sh createBuildScripts.sh
    - cd release
    - make
    - cd ../..
  artifacts:
    untracked: true
  only:
    - master

# run tests using the binary built before
test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - cd build
    - cd release
    - make test
  only:
    - master
```

With Visual Studio 2017 having cmake support built-in, I was wondering if there is now a similarly simple solution available for windows?