# How to use the new Visual Studio 2017 cmake features from terminal/script?

Tags: cmake, visual-studio-2017

This question is similar to [How to use the new Visual Studio 2017 cmake features with gitlab CI runners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43610616/how-to-use-the-new-visual-studio-2017-cmake-features-with-gitlab-ci-runners) but I didn't want to change the other question in case people are really looking for a specific gitlab-ci solution. If they are too similar than maybe this one should be closed.

Independently of gitlab-ci I would like to know how to compile cmake projects with the new Visual Studio 2017 from script or a command prompt. For previous versions `msbuild` was used together with a `*.sln` file (see [How do I compile a Visual Studio project from the command-line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498106/how-do-i-compile-a-visual-studio-project-from-the-command-line)). But now that you do no longer have to provide a `*.sln` file to open a project but can simply open a folder (and VS will take care of creating internally some sort of solution), I was wondering if things also get easier on the command line side.

Answer (score 1):

I would say no, VS 2017 does not make building CMake projects from the command line easier (yet).

Calling `devenv` commands with a directory will give an "unexpected error":

```
> devenv . /Build x86-Debug /Project HelloWorld

Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Version 15.0.26228.9.
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp. All rights reserved.

Visual Studio has encountered an unexpected error.
```

The CMake VS 2017 integration is just meant to better support CMake directly out-of the IDE (see also [Visual C++ Team Blog - CMake support in Visual Studio](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/10/05/cmake-support-in-visual-studio/)).

So just use plain `cmake` calls to build from the command line.

For the scripts I'm using in my projects to build VS from the command line see e.g. [Does CMake always generate configurations for all possible project configurations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38091010/does-cmake-always-generate-configurations-for-all-possible-project-configuration)

Comment: Very helpful link. Thank you.